# Digital Logic : Design a Calculator (or something similar to it)

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

So here's the story, We have been asked to design a Circuit (2 inputs each input has 2 bits) 
functions : add - sub- multiply - Exclusive OR
and 2 select lines (we will use 2 IC'S of 4x1 Multiplexer)

and then our prof. said our report should be computerized ( Truth Table, K-maps, Equations, and Pin Assignment)

I've finished all of them except Pin assignment... I don't even know what Pin Assignment mean.

Can someone explain?

Comment: What is "computerized"? Pin assignment makes sense if you are talking about some kind of FPGA design, where you assigning the pins of FPGA to be the IOs of your circuit. Or it could mean that you have to map the pins of your discrete parts to the signal names you are using in your design

Comment: Computerized as in, put everything in Microsoft word .

Comment: So, I have to use a program to do the Pin Assignment but I don't know what program I should use

Comment: So "computerize" is effectively "write". What in my comment made you think you need a computer program?

Comment: Is there a way to "write" This pin assignment in Microsoft word without a program? (i was thinking of designing it on a program then screenshot it and insert the image in Microsoft word)

Comment: Pin assignment is petty much a table. Draw one. You know, I haven't had a computer when was doing this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a PGA design it's simple enough, if you intended on doing this with discrete gates, pin assignment can also mean showing the assigned gates with associated pins on the schematic..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcFGsW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>